# UITableView - How to change the background color of cell during drag drop?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm implementing drag and drop between two UITableView's. 
When dragging an item over tableView, the tableView automatically displays the space where the new cell will be inserted. I'd like to highlight that space by changing the background color.

Currently, the space for the new cell shows in white. If I change the background color of UITableView, then the space reflects the corresponding background color. However, I do not want to change the background color for the tableView.

Can someone help on how I can achieve it?

Here's a screenshot of the functionality that I'm looking for.

[image: see screenshot]

Thanks,
Felix.J

Comment: Add the code that you have already tried.

Comment: I've implemented Drag-Drop in UICollectionView. I don't think the functionality you are looking for is currently supported by the API.

Comment: @PGDev My code won't help solve the issue or even answer it. I've coded the drag drop using the references in the below link. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view.

The functionality that I'm looking for can be seen in Things 3 app.

Comment: Please add the screenshot from Things 3 app.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: What `UITableViewDropIntent` are you using? Try using `insertIntoDestinationIndexPath`.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a new row and therefore I'm using UITableViewDropIntent.insertAtDestinationIndexPath. Like I said, tableView automatically displays the space where the new cell will be inserted (in white color). I just need to change the color (of that proposed cell space) to something else (gray for example).

Comment: Hey @FelixMarianayagam ... did you solve your problem? I am also wondering... (you might have solved that one as well...) when picking up the cell, I'd like the background of it to not be visible, but the snapshot always displays a translucent white background. Any idea?

Comment: Did somebody figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

Depending on if you're trying to set the background of the future location of the cell or the cell itself, you can alter the background and add effects to the drag cell by calling the `dragPreviewParametersForRowAt` function. For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {

        let param = UIDragPreviewParameters()
        param.backgroundColor = .clear
        return param
}
```

would remove the default white backdrop while a cell is being dragged within a table view.

Comment: This won't solve it. See the image I posted and notice how the space gets highlighted in gray color (round rect).

Comment: There is also `dropPreviewParametersForRowAt` that has to be declared with the same body